# Flyway DB - Deprecated Version

Tags: flyway

is there a way to know when a version of Flyway is going to get deprecated?, actually we were using 6.0.7 the last year and then got deprecated like 6 months ago, now we are using 6.4.1 but I tried to find something on the blog and documentation but there's nothing about some news of when a version is going to be deprecated, only when we run our java spring boot project we know that a version is not usable. And we're aware of this because there's a lot of changes in version 7+ that doesn't work with our project (tested version 7.0.1 and the app crashed) and we need to estimate the cost of the changes.

Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Flyway deprecates features (on each major release after the notification) not entire versions. Could you clarify what you mean exactly - it sounds like you are asking if something else is deprecating support for particular versions of Flyway but you have not stated what the something else is.

Comment: I mean, if the versión 6.4.1 of the core is going to be deprecated sooner or later, because when I compile the project, the pom version go to the repository to get the file and can't download it, so that's what I mean, if I can find somewhere to read about the version deprecated at the moment and when are the next ones going to be deprecated.

And need time to implement a new version and some changes within the java and maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Flyway releases via Maven OSS. Old versions are kept indefinitely and are outside of Redgate's control. In theory, all older versions which are currently available on Maven will continue to be available for all time.

Newer versions may deprecate features over time, but older versions will always be available.